# REXX Trace and SAY not displaying on the screen

Tags: trace, rexx

I am calling a REXX EXEC from another REXX EXEC in an interactive ISPF environment and my TRACE and SAY statements are not appearing on my terminal. Any ideas why that might be?

I'm expecting the TRACE and SAY statements to display on my terminal.

Comment: Might need a bit more info than what you have have supplied.  Where was the trace and say statements bring issue, The Calling REXX or the called REXX ?